# Generic Parent Class Extender

Tags: java, spring-boot, lombok

I have 2 parent classes, and a child class, and I am trying to make this flow work (Please note, I know there are other workarounds and whatnot, but I am not trying to initialize the variable in a constructor and stuff, this is just a proof of concept):

```
public class Child{
    String testVar1;
}

public class ParentA extends Child{
    String testVar2;
}

public class ParentA extends Child{
    Boolean testVar3;
}
```

I also have a method that was like this:

```
public Child createChild(){
    return new Child("testString")
}

// the method being called ▼ ▼ ▼ ▼
public ParentA createParentA(){
    return (ParentA) createChild();
}

public ParentB createParentB(){
    return (ParentB) createChild();
}
```

This, of course fails, since you cannot instantiate a parent class with typecasting a child class. I am trying to make all uncalled variables in the parent class become null, so in this case, it is supposed to create an object that looks like this:

```
{
    testVar1 = "hello",
    testVar2 = null
}
```

I also had an idea where we would do something like:

```
public <T> T createChild(Class<T> parentclass){
    return (parentClass) new Child("testString")
}

// the method being called ▼ ▼ ▼ ▼
public ParentA createParentA(){
    return createChild(ParentA.class);
}

public ParentB createParentB(){
    return createChild(ParentB.class);
}
```

I know this isn't the right way to code it, but you get the idea of what I am trying to do. Any way to get the method to directly cast to the parent class?

Comment: This really sounds like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). What is your ultimate goal by achieving this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This definitely sounds like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). In that your request is weird: It's really hard to come up with plausible use cases *where this line of thought leads to the best answer*. It's rather easy to come up with scenarios where this is one solution, and not a very good one - other solutions would be better. Hence, likely, you're in the second situation and you should take a step back and explain the underlying problem.

In the unlikely case you really want to go down this road:

There are 3 different ways to tackle this.

### With reflective access to constructors

You must create constructors in the sub classes (note that in your examples you've named the superclass `Child` and the subclasses `Parent`. This is precisely the wrong way around! To avoid confusion I shall use the term 'superclass' and 'subclass', but, really, ordinarily, it'd be `class Parent {}` and `class Child1 extends Parent {}` and `class Child2 extends Parent {}` in common parlance).

These constructors would have to take in an instance of the supertype, and it would copy over all relevant fields, and set the rest to the desired default value:

```
public class Super {
    String testVar1;

    public Super(String testVar1) {
      this.testVar1 = testVar1;
    }
}

public class SubA extends Super {
    String testVar2;

    public SubA(Super s) {
      super(s.getTestVar1());
      this.testVar2 = "";
    }
}

public class SubB extends Super {
    boolean testVar3;

    public SubB(Super s) {
      super(s.getTestVar1());
      this.testVar3 = false;
    }
}
```

As a slight variation on the theme, alternatively your `Super` class can have a constructor that takes an instance of `Super` and copies everything it can. Especially useful if `Super` has lots of properties.

The problem with constructors is: They exist entirely outside of the hierarchical type system. It is **not** possible to define an interface, or in any other way imply that a given class has a certain constructor. Hence, you're forced to use reflection, and if someone writes an error (does not follow the contract), you won't know until runtime. In other words, this system would require that all subtypes have a constructor like that, but if you write a subtype that doesn't, you don't get any compile-time warnings or errors:

```
static <T> T create(Class<T> type, Super base) {
  return type.getConstructor(Super.class).newInstance(base);
}
```

### Factories

There's a reason java has lots of factories: They are the way to fix that problem where static methods and constructors aren't part of the hierarchical type system. A factory solves this problem by adding a layer: A factory is an instance of an object, and one of its methods makes instances of the thing it is a factory of. This way, the 'make a thing' method is an instance method which **do** participate in the typing system, thus, you can make an interface for it:

```
public interface FooFactory<F extends Super> {
  F create(Super base);
}

// Super, SubA and SubB are essentially just as above.

public class SubAFactory implements FooFactory<SubA> {
  public static final SubAFactory INSTANCE = new SubAFactory();

  @Override public SubA create(Super base) {
    return new SubA(base);
  }
}
```

It's a little bit of extra code, but there is now no longer any need to mess with reflection, and any violation of the setup (such as failing to have that constructor) now *does* result in compile time errors, which is good. If your case is truly this simple, the code can also be extremely simple:

```
public class SubA extends Super {
  // all the stuff as above. And also...

  public static final FooFactory<SubA> FACTORY = SubA::new;
}
```

That one line is then all you need.

### Lombok

I noticed you tagged this question with lombok. This feels a bit like boilerplate, so you might be thinking: Huh, I wonder if lombok can generate these factories or reflective 'constructors' perhaps.

No. It's not *common*  boilerplate. This isn't a common solution to any problem I'm aware of. Only *common boilerplate* is a candidate to get attention from Project Lombok.

SOURCE: I'm 50% of the body that decides what lombok does.